# Скрытие программных кнопок "Домой", "Назад" и т.д., если minSdk = 10

Tags: android, ui

Для скрытия программных кнопок "Домой", "Назад" и т.д. используется  `setSystemUiVisibility (int visibility)`, которая появилась в API 11. А я использую API 10 (для поддержки версий 2.3.3-2.3.7), как мне тогда скрывать программные кнопки на более новых версиях андроида?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно делают так

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
    setSystemUiVisibility (...)
} else {
   // do nothing
}
```

Понятно, что эта проверка выноситься в отдельный метод вида

```
bool ... isGINGERBREAD_MR1_AVAIBLE()
{
    return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1;
}
```

Посмотреть

- [Build.VERSION_CODES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)
- [Get android api level of phone currently running my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993924/get-android-api-level-of-phone-currently-running-my-application)

Comment: а можно пойти ещё дальше. Создается класс с названием ScreenUtils или NetworkUtils. Абстрактный. А потом пишется две-три его реализации для разных апи. Теперь нужно будет только один раз инстацировать по текущему апи. Это удобно, если методы можно сгруппировать.

Comment: Так у меня же API 10 и поэтому нет доступа к этой функции, так как она появилась только в API 11.

Comment: какой функции?

Comment: setSystemUiVisibility()

Comment: Код выше проверяет текущую версию системы, где запускается программа и вызывает метод только в том случае, если версия подходящая (выше 10). В противном случае ничего не будет делаться.

А вот скомпилировать этот кусок кода получиться, так как скорее всего Вы будете использовать компилятор с sdk более высокой версии.